# error loading json file containing array with an array element

Tags: java, json, arrays

I'm writing a loader/saver for a little android game im working on. I'm saving it as a json file by creating a json object for each 'actor' in my game, putting them into a jsonarray, then writing the `jsonarray.tojsonstring()` to the file.

here is how I'm saving, I call the save level method which adds each actor to the array using `addActor()` then calls the `writefile()` method

```
    public void addActor(Actor actor, int index, JSONArray actorArray) {
    if (actor != null) {
        System.out.println("adding actor " + actor.name);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Adding nulla ctor");
    }
    if (actors[index] != null) {
    } else {
        actors[index] = new JSONObject();
        actors[index].put("index", index);
        actors[index].put("bodyname", actor.name);
        actors[index].put("restitution", actor.body.getFixtureList().get(0).getRestitution());
        actors[index].put("density", actor.body.getFixtureList().get(0).getDensity());
        actors[index].put("friction", actor.body.getFixtureList().get(0).getFriction());
        actors[index].put("startx", actor.startX);
        actors[index].put("starty", actor.startY);
        actors[index].put("startrotation", actor.startAngle);
        actors[index].put("rotationspeed", actor.rotSpeed);
        actors[index].put("enabled", actor.enabled);
        actors[index].put("numPaths", actor.numPaths);
        if (actor.numPaths > 0) {
            JSONArray[] pathx = new JSONArray[actor.getNumPaths()];
            JSONArray[] pathy = new JSONArray[actor.getNumPaths()];
            JSONArray[] pathspeed = new JSONArray[actor.getNumPaths()];
            for (int i = 0; i < actor.getNumPaths(); i++) {
                pathx[i] = new JSONArray();
                pathy[i] = new JSONArray();
                pathspeed[i] = new JSONArray();
                for (int j = 0; j < actor.getPath(i).size; j++) {
                    pathx[i].add(actor.getPath(i).points[j].x);
                    pathy[i].add(actor.getPath(i).points[j].y);
                    pathspeed[i].add(actor.getPath(i).points[j].speed);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("added " + actor.name + ", " + pathx.length + " paths.");
            actors[index].put("pathx", pathx);
            actors[index].put("pathy", pathy);
            actors[index].put("pathspeed", pathspeed);
        }
        //indices.add(index);
        actorArray.add(actors[index]);
    }
}


public void writeFile(String name, JSONArray actorArray) {
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\mojo\\Desktop\\svn\\Ball\\src\\com\\moe\\ball\\levels\\" + name + ".json");
        writer.write(actorArray.toJSONString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public void saveLevel(String levelName, BallScreen screen) {
    JSONArray actorArray = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < screen.maxActor; i++) {
        addActor(screen.actorList[i], i, actorArray);
    }
    writeFile(levelName, actorArray);

}
```

Sorry, theres a lot of random stuff in there from when I was figuring out the json library and trying to figure things out. heres a snippet of code use to test if its loading right

```
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\mojo\\Desktop\\svn\\Ball\\src\\com\\moe\\ball\\levels\\" + name + ".json"));
        JSONObject obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            obj = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
            System.out.println("bodyname " + i + ": " + obj.get("bodyname"));
        }
```

When loading any level that has an actor with multiple movepaths(which therefore has an array inside one of the elements of the main array of actors) I get an error on the 
`JSONArray array = ....`  line that says:

```
Unexpected character (L) at position 50.
```

heres a little snippet from the json file so you can see what it looks like where it is causing problems

```
[{"enabled":true,"index":0,"density":0.6,"pathy":[Lorg.json.simple.JSONArray;@39d3da65,"friction":0.6,"rotationspe
the \`L\` in \`[Lorg.json....\` is at position 50.
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question I'm very new to this, I did spend hours searching and if I dont find an answer here I'm just going to try a different json library(I'm using json.simple now)

Comment: Which json library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to store a Java array of `JSONArray`s as the `pathx` and `pathy` attributes of your JSON object. You should store a `JSONArray` of `JSONArray`s instead.

Comment: so I just make a jsonarray, and add jsonarrays as elements?

Comment: Yes, that's what you should do.